# how to mute AxShockwaveFlash in c#

Tags: c#, axshockwaveflash

I am using `AxShockwaveFlash` in windows form Application .I am able to manage the context menu. Can I manage the sound of the flash playing in `AxShockwaveFlash`?

Answer (score 0):

Flash ActiveX itself doesn't have such property or function, you have to use wrappers like f-in-box: [f-in-box: how to enable / disable flash sounds](http://f-in-box.com/dotnet/features.html#feature_enable_disable_flash_sounds).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with that class but I quick search yielded

`AxShockwaveFlash axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlash();
axShockwaveFlash1.FlashVars = "auto_play=true&channel=adventuretimed&start_volume=25";`

It looks like you can set volume in the FlashVars attribute.